# Load script after inserting it to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="abc"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to insert script in div and run it.
So im doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="<script>alert('sup');</script>";
```

Good, script is inside that div, but how can i run it now?

I propably didn't make it clear:
I have an external script that i need to put in specified place on the page. 
I don't have access to the website, so i can't put it on the page code.
I want to do this, becouse this script makes new objects on the place where it is putted.
I don't have access to that script. I just have link (not direct) to it.

Comment: Why do you want the script element *in* the div? What are you trying to accomplish? Your example js code can be replaced by just `alert('sup');` for the same result.

Comment: Becouse its adding stuff on the page in the place where it is putted. I want to run external js.

Comment: thats because there is no info on when it should be called. When do you want the script to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function. Use `<script>function myAlert(){alert('sup');}</script>` instead. You can then call it with `myAlert();`.

Comment: Take it a step further: `function myAlert2(){ return myAlert(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Please use createElement for that

```
var div = document.getElementById('abc');
var script = document.createElement('script');
var code = document.createTextNode('alert("sup");');
script.appendChild(code);
div.appendChild(script);
```

To put a script in a div is only useful for `document.write` And please don't do that. :-)

Comment: I dont want to run alert window. I just used it as example. I need to insert that script code first at the specified place, and after that run inserted script. It is adding stuff in the place where it is putted.

Comment: Replace `alert` with everything you want.

Comment: He wants to `alert('sup')`not `alert("Hello")` :P @alexP

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand. That's complicated :-) @l2aelba